# how to block android's key pad and make user to enter values from On-screen buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

[My actual screen shot tested on device](http://i1295.photobucket.com/albums/b635/Binoy0007/Trial7_zps59ae8705.png)

I have a text field ( with a default hint "Enter Grade" ), whenever I touch the text field, the keypad of my device pops up.

My Problem: I dont want the user to enter the input text from his keypad, I want him to use my on-screen buttons ( like S or A or ...) to enter the numeric values ( 10 or 9.. respectively ). How to acheive this? or any better solution for that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried setting `android:inputType=none`

Comment: Please check this question [`"Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard"`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1109022/1870450) for hiding and showing the Android soft keyboard. After hiding the keyboard you will ready to show the your custom view for input. Check [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1109108/1870450) also. May this helpful to you..

Comment: Thank you realAndroid, shouldI place those codes in activity_man.xml ?? (I m just a starter thx). But How can I make Onscreen buttons to enter numeric values in text boxes which were selected by users?

Comment: You need to implement custom keyboard the sample project is (https://www.dropbox.com/s/4u6sylh64wpi7fd/Custom%20Keyboard.zip) . Check it out and changes as your need.